# Allow empty list in serializers.ListField

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST framework 3.3 and am trying to serialize a list that could be empty with the provided serializers.ListField class that is included in the framework. My current instantiation of the field looks like this

```
 countrypreferences = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(),
                                            source='country_preference_ids',
                                            allow_null=True)
```

When testing the API I always seem to get a 400 response if I let the field be an empty list. It would seem like this kind of functionality would be pretty common but I can't find a way to allow the empty list. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You should set:

```
child=serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would rather use

```
field = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), allow_empty=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to that you can also provide a default value to the ListField in the serializers

```
field = serializers.ListField(default = [])
```

This will set the field as an empty list if u send None or no value.

Comment: ListField(default=list) is better. Using default=[] might not cause problems everywhere, but using mutable defaults is a bad habit to get into, because it creates a mutable value that will be shared among callers that each expect to get a default value.